# How to get the form page url?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to get the live URL from which an HTML form has been submitted. Like a hidden input tag using a javascript function, which will send me the URL with the form submission. How can I do that?

Comment: for example add a submit event handler that will populate an hidden field value with `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `submit` event to your `form`, it will be executed shortly before submit action. And set value of hidden field.

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById('form');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  let myForm = document.getElementById('url').value = location.href;
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="html" id="url"> 
  <input type="submit"> 
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backend language is PHP, look for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. Other backend languages also have similar Referrer global variables.